# Multiple database in cakephp console app

Tags: php, mysql, schema, database-migration, cakephp-2.3

Following is my cake console code to generate database schema. I have to manage multiple database schema migration. When I am calling generateDb function it creates a master schema after that i am switching database connection to client database, but client schema is not generating. its again generating master schema.

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array('ClientDbdetail');
    public function generateDb() {
        $runCommand = shell_exec(APP.'Console/cake schema generate -f master');
        if ($runCommand) {
            $sessionArray = $this->ClientDbdetail->find('first', array('recursive' => -1));
            $this->__switchDb($sessionArray['ClientDbdetail']);
            shell_exec(APP.'Console/cake schema generate -f client');
            $this->out('Schema generated');
        } else {
            $this->out('Schema not generated');
        }
    }

    private function __switchDb(array $userDetail) {
        $username = 'default';
        $settings = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 3306,
            'login' => $userDetail['user_dbuser'],
            'password' => $userDetail['user_dbpwd'],
            'database' => $userDetail['user_dbname'],
            'prefix' => ''
        );
        ConnectionManager::drop($username);
        ConnectionManager::create($username, $settings);
        ConnectionManager::getDataSource($username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From CakePHP book there is an example.

```
public $connection = 'default';

public function before($event = array()) {
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->connection);
    $db->cacheSources = false;
    return true;
}
```

and after :

```
public function before($event = array()) {
    $articles = ClassRegistry::init('Articles', array(
        'ds' => $this->connection
    ));
    // Do things with articles.
}
```

see this : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html